# Consolidating duplicate tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, tag-synonyms

I'm noticing that there are a fair number of duplicate tags, which is surprising considering you need a really high rep to create tags - I would have thought users would know better.

For example, there are 17 articles with "action" and 7 with "actions" as their tags. This just dilutes the knowledgebase IMHO. Unless there's a really specific reason to disambiguate between the two (I suppose a case could be made in this instance that "action" would be appropriate for a question relating to a specific action hook, whereas "actions" would be relating to the collection of action hooks in general). Regardless, a poster might not be aware of these specifics and would just choose arbitrarily.

What can be done? Is there a feature for mods to consolidate tags? Or re-assign? How can I help (my rep is pitiful here)?

Comment: When this site was still in a startup phase, it took [only 150 rep to create a new tag](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags), so we got many tags from there. Creating tag synonyms requires way more rep, and we just didn't have enough people to do that. I support the moderators if they would be more "brutal" in doing this themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes very considerable 2500 rep to even [suggest tag synonyms](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) and from there they must be voted on to be applied. So the process of getting tag in order is sluggish so far.

I had exercised my recently acquired diamond to merge [action](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/action) into [actions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actions) and [filter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter) into [filters](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filters), according to past discussion that plural form makes more sense for such stuff and for filters it was dominating with huge lead.

Please do not hesitate to continue posting your suggestions on meta if you notice any other tags that should be obviously merged.

Comment: Outstanding. While we're on the topic (or maybe I should post another question) I wonder whether "action-hooks" are more appropriate than "actions"?

Comment: And gratz on the diamond BTW. I don't even want to imagine how active you must be here to achieve that, considering how new this stackexchange is.

Comment: @Tom Auger hmmm... I think _actions_ is sufficiently self-explanatory in context of WP